# how to see my managed objects on the stack?

Tags: .net, debugging, sos

I use SOS.dll in VisualStudio to debug my C# program. The program is as below.

The debug command is *!DumpStackObjects*.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Int32 result = f(1);
    }

    static Int32 f(Int32 i)
    {
        Int32 j = i + 1;
        return j;            <===========BreakPoint is here
    }
}
```

After I input the "!dso" command in the immediate window of Visual Studio, the result is as below:

> OS Thread Id: 0xf6c (3948)
>
> ESP/REG  Object   Name

Why there's nothing? I thought there should be the args i and local variable j.

Thanks for my answering my naive questions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!dumpstackobject` dumps references on the stack to objects. I.e. you won't see value types with this command. Use `!clrstack -l` to see locals (use `-p` to see parameters, and `-a` for both).

Comment: Thanks, Brian. Is there any commands in the SOS.dll to get a list of varibales on stack? Do I have to use WinDbg?

Comment: Keep in mind that locals/parameters may be stored in registers so for an optimized build you may not be able to see all the details - even in WinDbg.

Comment: Also, since you're loading SOS in VS, why not just use the Locals, Watch, or the Immediate window to watch locals?

Comment: Thanks Brian, your answer is very informative. I just want to view what's going on on the stack in the most native and primitive way.

Comment: I have limited experience with SOS in VS, but I use it on a regular basis from WinDbg. You should also check out sosex.dll and psscor2.dll.

Comment: Thanks Brian for telling me about sosex.dll and psscor2.dll. I will try them.